# cryptojs.decrypt returns empty result

Tags: javascript, typescript, aes, cryptojs, ecb

I need to decrypt a hex message in JavaScript that has the exact same outcome as the code written in Java. However the Javascript version using CryptoJs returns an empty result

Code in Java:

```
private static void create()
{
    byte[] sessionKey = fromHexString("dae25b4defd646cd99b7b95d450d6646");
    byte[] data = fromHexString("2700012e27999bdaa6b0530375be269985a0238e5e4baf1528ebaf34a8e5e8c13a58b25bcb82514ee6c86c02ff77ac52bdbd88");

    byte[] payload_data = new byte[48];
    byte[] decrypted_data = new byte[48];

    for(int i=0;i<48;i++) {
        payload_data[i]= data[3+i];
    }


    try{
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        decrypted_data = cipher.doFinal(payload_data);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    String my_data = byteArrayToHex(decrypted_data);
    System.out.println(my_data);
}

private static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
    for(byte b: a)
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    return sb.toString();
}

private static byte[] fromHexString(String src) {
    byte[] biBytes = new BigInteger("10" + src.replaceAll("\\s", ""), 16).toByteArray();
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(biBytes, 1, biBytes.length);
}
```

which returns a result of: "248A8143837F51E03C3522934DD47C38612C90EC57D79D7DE6174EAC85B75F9ADCD7D6686EBF4B9F2E9FE441D373E69E"

Code in JavaScript:

```
import * as cryptojs from 'crypto-js';

export function create() {
  const sessionKey = Buffer.from('dae25b4defd646cd99b7b95d450d6646', 'hex');
  const data = Buffer.from('2700012e27999bdaa6b0530375be269985a0238e5e4baf1528ebaf34a8e5e8c13a58b25bcb82514ee6c86c02ff77ac52bdbd88', 'hex');

  const payloadData = Buffer.alloc(48);

  for (let i = 0; i < 48; i += 1) {
    payloadData[i] = data[3 + i];
  }

  const decrypted = cryptojs.AES.decrypt(
    cryptojs.enc.Hex.parse(toHexString(payloadData)),
    cryptojs.enc.Hex.parse(toHexString(sessionKey)),
    {
      mode: cryptojs.mode.ECB,
      padding: cryptojs.pad.NoPadding,
    }
  ).toString(cryptojs.enc.Hex);

  console.log({
    decrypted,
  });
}

function toHexString(byteArray) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-bitwise
  return Array.prototype.map.call(byteArray, byte => `0${(byte & 0xff).toString(16)}`.slice(-2)).join('');
}
```

result:

```
{ decrypted: '' }
```

Any idea on what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decryption with CryptoJS could look as follows:

```js
function decrypt() {
    var sessionKey = 'dae25b4defd646cd99b7b95d450d6646';
    var data = '2700012e27999bdaa6b0530375be269985a0238e5e4baf1528ebaf34a8e5e8c13a58b25bcb82514ee6c86c02ff77ac52bdbd88';
    var payload_data = data.substr(6);
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        payload_data,
        CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(sessionKey),
        {
            format: CryptoJS.format.Hex,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
        }
    ).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    console.log(decrypted.replace(/(.{48})/g,'$1\n'));
}

decrypt();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

**Update:** Regarding your comment: The issue in your code is that the ciphertext is passed as `WordArray`. The following two changes are one way to make it work:

```
...
const decrypted = cryptojs.AES.decrypt(
    toHexString(payloadData),                           // pass the ciphertext as hex encoded string
    cryptojs.enc.Hex.parse(toHexString(sessionKey)),
    {
        format: cryptojs.format.Hex,                    // specify the encoding of the ciphertext
        mode: cryptojs.mode.ECB,
        ...
```

`cryptojs.AES.decrypt()` expects the ciphertext in a `CipherParams` object (and not simply in a `WordArray`). Alternatively the ciphertext can be passed Base64 encoded or in another encoding that must be specified explicitly with the `format` parameter (e.g. hexadecimal here, Base64 is the default). The ciphertext is then implicitly converted into a `CipherParams` object, see [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input).

But please consider: Since all conversions can be done with CryptoJS onboard means, helpers like `toHexString()` are not really necessary. For this there are especially the encoder classes, see [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders). The same applies to the NodeJS `Buffer`. It makes more sense to work with `WordArray`s, because they are processed directly by CryptoJS.

Comment: Works!! Thanks! Still not really clear what I did wrong in the example :(

Comment: @KobeLeysen - I added in my answer in the update section where in your code the bug is and what changes are necessary.